# Selecting the MAX Count based on a few criterias

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that groups the following fields and sums the Draw field

DelDate     |Plant  |Route      |Zip    |City   |State |Draw

2021-08-01  |0010   |0105003    |10467  |BRONX  |NY    |15

2021-08-01  |0010   |0105003    |10469  |BRONX  |NY    |60

2021-08-02  |0010   |0105003    |10467  |BRONX  |NY    |14

2021-08-02  |0010   |0105003    |10469  |BRONX  |NY    |62

How do I tell SQL to give me the row with the largest draw for a particular date and particular route.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the 'dominant' zip and the criteria for a dominant zip is the zip with the highest draw for the same date and route.

Results should be

2021-08-01  |0010   |0105003    |10469  |BRONX  |NY |60

2021-08-02  |0010   |0105003    |10469  |BRONX  |NY |62

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or u can use MAX-function with PARTITION BY

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DelDate 
            ,Plant 
            ,Route 
            ,Zip 
            ,City 
            ,State 
            ,Draw
            ,MAX(Draw) OVER (PARTITION BY DelDate, Route) AS MaxDraw
     FROM @data) d
     WHERE Draw = DelDateMaxDraw
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cross-apply to join an aggregate.

```
declare @data table (DelDate datetime, Plant  int, Route int, Zip int, City varchar(50), State varchar(2), Draw int)
insert into @data values (cast('2021-08-01' as datetime), 0010, 0105003, 10467, 'BRONX','NY',15)
insert into @data values (cast('2021-08-01' as datetime), 0010, 0105003, 10469, 'BRONX','NY',60)
insert into @data values (cast('2021-08-02' as datetime), 0010, 0105003, 10467, 'BRONX','NY',14)
insert into @data values (cast('2021-08-02' as datetime), 0010, 0105003, 10469, 'BRONX','NY',62)
select d1.* from @data d1 cross apply (
select top 1 zip, max(draw) as max from @data group by zip order by 2 desc) d2
where d1.zip = d2.zip
```

[image]